# typescript fetch response streaming

Tags: node.js, typescript, stream, fetch

i am trying to stream a response. But i want to be able to read the response (and work with the data) while it is still being sent. I basically want to send multiple messages in one response.

It works internally in node.js, but when i tried to do the same thing in typescript it doesnt work anymore.

My attempt was to do the request via fetch in typescript and the response is coming from a node.js server by writing parts of the response on the response stream.

```
fetch('...', {
    ...
}).then((response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    reader.read().then(({done, value}) => {
        if (done) {
            return response;
        }
            console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, value)); //just for testing purposes
    })
}).then(...)...
```

On the Node.js side it basically looks like this:

```
// doing stuff with the request
response.write(first_message)
// do some more stuff
response.write(second_message)
// do even more stuff
response.end(last_message)
```

In Node.js, like i said, i can just read every message once its sent via res.on('data', ...), but the reader.read in typescript only triggers(?) once and that is when the whole response was sent.

Is there a way to make it work like i want, or do i have to look for another way?

I hope it is kinda understandable what i want to do, i noticed while writing this how much i struggled explaining this :D

Comment: If the two write are kinda consecutive, it's a normal behavior. Try to add a timeout between writes server side.

Comment: I just tried that and put a 15 second timeout in there, but it sadly didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and as usual it was sitting in front of the pc.

I forgot to write a header first, before writing the response.